# Condition inside linQ Where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following object:

```
public class Result
{
    public List<Recomendation> Recomendations { get; set; }
}

public class Recomendation
{
    public List<Segment> Segments { get; set; }
}

public class Segment
{
    public Leg OutBound { get; set; }  
    public Leg InBound { get; set; }   
}

public class Leg
{
    public TimeSpan TotalTime { get; set; }
    public string Carrier { get; set; }
    public int RefNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have a List called `recommendations`

I need to do this:

- Filter `recommendations` by occurrence of a string  `arr` in  `Carrier`, inside either the outbound or the inbound objects. I tried doing this:

Search Inbound alone:

```
var filteredList = recommendations.Where( r=>r.Segments.Any(x => x.InBound.Carrier.Contains(arr))).ToList();
```

or search outbound alone:

```
var filteredList = recommendations.Where( r=>r.Segments.Any(x => x.OutBound.Carrier.Contains(arr))).ToList();
```

I want to search for the occurrence of the string `arr` in **BOTH** inbound and outbound.

The problem is sometimes InBound can be null or OutBound can be null. I want my linQ to work in either cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that the code won't break when either Inbound or Outbound is null.

```
var filteredList = recommendations.Where( r=>r.Segments.Any(x =>  ( x.OutBound != null && x.OutBound.Carrier.Contains(arr)) || (x.Inbound != null && x.InBound.Carrier.Contains(arr))).ToList();
```

Comment: This worked in case both InBound and OutBound are not null. When One of them is Null, it returns all the items in recommendations

Comment: I had to remove the first part of the condition : x.Inbound == null || x.Outbound == null. check my answer. thanks.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut I thought you needed when Inbound and Outbound was null too

Answer (score 2):

You could do this if you are using C# 6.0:

```
var filteredList = recommendations.Where( r=>r.Segments.Any(x => x?.InBound.Carrier.Contains(arr) 
                                                              || x?.OutBound.Carrier.Contains(arr) ))
                                  .ToList();
```

Take a look [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had to take [@raven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892720/raven)'s answer and modify it a bit. Here's the solution:

```
var filteredList = recommendations.Where( r=>r.Segments.Any(x => ( x.OutBound != null && x.OutBound.Carrier.Contains(arr)) || (x.Inbound != null && x.InBound.Carrier.Contains(arr)))).ToList();
```